# Recoverying from exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, sandbox, error-recovery

In our application (c++) we load 3rd party DLLs using LoadLibrary.
Sometimes these DLLs cause exceptions, such as "Access violation reading location 0x00000000..".

Is it possible to recover from such an exception, for example using try & catch or some other mechanism? in other world, is that possible to create a sandbox within the same process that withstand such events?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it? Also, wouldn't it be better to submit a bug report to the third-party supplier about it, so it's fixed instead of stepping around the problem?

Comment: try & catch didn't help, we load many many 3rd party DLLs and we don't have any sort of control over them.

Comment: Well, you could compile with /EHa, do a SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(...) and then test for access violations and throw a C++ exception and catch it just outside of LoadLibrary(...). This is hackish and you need to ensure thread safety, but it would work to just determine if a plugin is bad or good - after all, you can always just mark the plugin as 'bad' and restart the app without it to avoid 'hidden' corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different type of exception handler:

```
__try
{
    // Code that might cause an access violation goes here. 

}
__except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
    int code = _exception_code();

}
```

Beware though, such handlers can't be used in any routine where C++ objects need stack unwinding as the compiler will warn you (irritatingly).

Comment: ... that is, almost in the whole C++, right? RAII and STL all rely on destructors to free the resources.

Comment: @Vlad - if it were that simple then you'd almost never be able to use this type of exception handler in C++ - but you can. You just have to be careful *where* you put it, adding an extra layer of function calls if necessary to wrap the problematic code.

Comment: indeed, a lot of C++ code is written as "just C code with virtual functions". For such a code, this low-level technique would work. But I doubt that there is some valid application of this technique within a program part which uses e.g. RAII.

Comment: @Vlad - not so. Consider a method where such objects are passed in by reference - even non-const reference. You can quite happily use such a handler within that method since no unwinding is required *within*that*method*. It's locally-declared objects that cause problems with such a handler.

Comment: Yep, i got the "Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding"

Comment: @kambi - have a look and see if you can isolate the calls to the DLLs into their own methods within your code, methods that pass in everything you need (by ref) rather than declare them locally. It might seem an unnecessary layer, but if you only declare simple data types locally then you *should* be able to use the handler.

Comment: @JTeagle: well -- but passing by reference defeats the very purpose of e.g. smart pointers.

Comment: @Vlad - We're talking about finding a way to add robustness to some code. If you have to sacrifice something small to achieve that, so be it.

Comment: @JTeagle: Yes. And the robust solution IMO is just crash. Trying to recover the part of a program hoping that it doesn't use certain valid and popular techniques, leaving the program internals in inconsistent state and possibly corrupting user's data -- I wouldn't call this approach "robust". More on the topic by Raimund Chen: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/13/9921676.aspx (see the 2nd part about global exception handler).

Comment: @Vlad - this has nothing to do with 'global' exception handlers. We're talking about a tight handler around a single DLL call. At worst, the DLL's state is indeterminate. No corruption of data unless the DLL did that - and it was doing it anyway - we just 'caught' it after the act. Most users would prefer a program to try and continue as best as it can with a warning (and give them a chance to save and exit) rather than simply die on them. What happens to the rest of their entered and unsaved data if you simply crash? Backups are the way to stop corrupt data being a problem.

Comment: @JTeagle: I think there is a misconception here. It's not a DLL what crashed, it's a _process_ what crashed. You never know in which state the stack is after such a crash. The crashed code may have smashed the whole your heap or global structures. The program is in inconsistent state -- the whole one!

Comment: @JTeagle: Additionally, I am not sure that your interpretation of what is safe and not regarding destruction of objects is fine. If the stack is not being unwound the issue is not just in the local function that contains the `__try/__except`, but also in the function that was called from it. If the DLL allocates memory into an smart pointer and then the error is raised, I doubt that the compiler will inject code for stack unwinding inside the DLL (releasing the smart pointer) and not for your function. The fact that you silence the compiler does not mean it is safe.

Comment: @JTeagle: That is, if your statement that the stack will not be unwound is true... a cursory look at the documentation seems to indicate that with /EHsc the stack might actually be unwound, in which case I do not understand why the compiler might warn you about anything...

Comment: @David - I did say 'stack unwinding' but it was the wrong word - the compiler says "Cannot use __try in functions that require *object* unwinding" if you try and put this type of handler in a method that includes local object declarations. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

No. It's not. A DLL has unrestricted access to the process context that calls it. You need to run untrustable DLLs in their own process context.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, with VisualStudio compiler, may use **SEH** mechanism.

```
__try
{
  char* ptr = 0;
  char val = *ptr;
}
__except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
{
  std::cout<<"AV"<<std::endl;
}
```

Use option **/EHa**.

Comment: Nice -- and what can you do with the program after having this caught? The whole thing is now in undefined behaviour situation.

Comment: Well, if program throws a access-violation exception, her affairs are very, very bad... Maybe, in the handler it can save some very important data? Or, report on their crash?

Comment: according to Raimund Chen, the best idea is to let the program crash: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/13/9921676.aspx (I've already posted this link in some another comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `/EH` flag - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx - in Visual Studio, but access violation exceptions most likely mean you're doing something very wrong. I'd let the program crash and try to solve the exception, rather than catching it.

Comment: Access violation is likely to be not an exception from C++ point of view.

Comment: @Vlad: Right, but that flag enables you to use implementation-specific exception handlers, to catch OS exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in c++ if, it is not possible throws a crossmodules exceptions anymore in any case you will have a memory corruption in your application so you have to find out what is going wrong in your dll. You can check the reason you cant throw exception from dll here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Answer (score 1):

The people behind Runtime-Compiled C++ are using a thing called *Structured Exception Handling* for [their DLL crash-handling routines](http://runtimecompiledcplusplus.blogspot.fr/2011/09/crash-protection.html). Dig into their website or ask them if you want some code samples.

According to the MSDN, the `/EHa` switch enables "C++ exception handling with structured exception handling exceptions". So if you're using the `msvc` compiler, you might want to try this.